# React, Vue microfrontend communication inside a javascript host application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I have microfrontend remote components using REACT and VUE. I want to use these components inside a  host application(.net) using vanilla JS. I am currently using module federation to load remote components into the host application. How can I share state between these components. In another way how can one component communicate with another component?

Answer (score 2):

The basic way is EventListener Bus. example: Your Vue Component is triggering event, and your React Component is listening this event. When event is fired, react will start own actions.

You can use [single-spa](https://single-spa.js.org/) library for that. It supports vanillaJS

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the best way I've found has been with the [broadcastChannel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API). Here is a [react hooks implementation of it](https://github.com/trevoro/use-broadcast/blob/master/index.js) that worked great in a WebPack module federations MFE setup.